# uploading video frames with ASIFormDataRequest?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

Is it possible to upload frames of the capturing video with ASIFormDataRequest?

code i have:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        frameCount = 0;
        [myQueue cancelAllOperations];
        [myQueue setDelegate:self];
        NSString *urlString = @"url";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

        objReturner = [[ReturnerClass alloc] init];
        NSError *deviceError;
        AVCaptureDevice *cameraDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:cameraDevice error:&deviceError];

        // make output device
        AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *outputDevice = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
        outputDevice.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey: (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
        [outputDevice setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

        // initialize capture session
        self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
        [self.captureSession addInput:inputDevice];
        [self.captureSession addOutput:outputDevice];

        // make preview layer and add so that camera's view is displayed on screen
        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:self.captureSession];
        previewLayer.frame = self.previewLayer.bounds;
        [self.previewLayer.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
        [self.captureSession startRunning];

    }




-(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection
    {
        //[connection setVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 30)];
        /*We create an autorelease pool because as we are not in the main_queue our code is
         not executed in the main thread. So we have to create an autorelease pool for the thread we are in*/


        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        /*Lock the image buffer*/
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
        /*Get information about the image*/
        uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

        /*Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef*/
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
        CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);

        /*We release some components*/
        CGContextRelease(newContext);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

        /*We display the result on the custom layer. All the display stuff must be done in the main thread because
         UIKit is no thread safe, and as we are not in the main thread (remember we didn't use the main_queue)
         we use performSelectorOnMainThread to call our CALayer and tell it to display the CGImage.*/
        //[self.customLayer performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setContents:) withObject: (id) newImage waitUntilDone:YES];

        /*We display the result on the image view (We need to change the orientation of the image so that the video is displayed correctly).
         Same thing as for the CALayer we are not in the main thread so ...*/
        UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];

        /*We relase the CGImageRef*/
        CGImageRelease(newImage);

        //[self.imageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:YES];

        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.1);     //change Image to NSData



        [self sendFrameToServer:imageData];
        /*We unlock the  image buffer*/
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);


    }


-(void)sendFrameToServer:(NSData *)imageData{
        [request setData:imageData withFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i_%@.png",frameCount,[objReturner returnTimeStamp]] andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"imagetoupload"];
        [request startSynchronous];
        [myQueue addOperation:request];
        NSLog(@"Value: %@",[request responseString]);
        frameCount++;
    }
```

i am declaring myQueue and request object in the .h

The problem i have here is that the NSLog response always shows the first image that was send to the server, it never changes for example "Value: The file 0_2013-03-14 19:27:34.png has been uploaded" stays like this the whole time, while the frameCount is being increased and the date seconds doesnt even goes up.

Is there an solution for this?

Comment: Only use the [tag:Xcode]  tag for questions directly about the tool itself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once try  by using Delegate methods like,

```
-(void)sendFrameToserver:(NSData *)imageData {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_URL_TO_POST"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setUseKeychainPersistence:YES];
    [request setData:imageData withFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i_%@.png",frameCount,[objReturner returnTimeStamp]] andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"imagetoupload"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];

   }
```

Now write your delegate methods,

```
- (void)uploadRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{    

     NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
     NSLog( @"response--%@",responseString );

   }
 - (void)uploadRequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

    NSLog(@" Error - Statistics file upload failed: \"%@\"",[[request error] localizedDescription]);

   }
```

hope it will be helpful to you....